# MonoDevelop requires the Mono Framework 2.4 or later

Tags: monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop 2.2 for the Mac OS X and when I start I get the error described on the title. The weird thing is that I already installed the mono framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: MonoDevelop's startup script detects the Mono version using `mono --version`. What's the output of that command?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 2.4.2.3 (tarball Mon aug 31 09:54:11 MDT 2009)
TLS: normal
GC: Included Boehm (with typed GC)
SIGSEGV: normal
Notification: Thread + polling
Architecture x86
Disabled: none

Comment: here's a log I retrieved when opening monodevelop:
Sep 16 18:10:39 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro [0x0-0x95095].com.ximian.monodevelop[1982]: 16:184: 
Sep 16 18:10:39 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro [0x0-0x95095].com.ximian.monodevelop[1982]: execution error: User canceled. (-128)
Sep 16 18:10:39 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro [0x0-0x95095].com.ximian.monodevelop[1982]: Cannot launch MonoDevelop

Comment: Sep 16 18:10:39 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro [0x0-0x95095].com.ximian.monodevelop[1982]: MonoDevelop requires the Mono Framework version 2.4 or later.
Sep 16 18:10:39 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro com.apple.launchd[72] ([0x0-0x95095].com.ximian.monodevelop[1982]): Exited with exit code: 1
Sep 16 18:10:50 jonas-stawskis-macbook-pro [0x0-0x96096].com.ximian.monodevelop[2006]: /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/monodevelop: line 35: grep: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently my Mac OS X installation was corrupted and the grep command (among other commands) was missing. It seems like MonoDevelop uses the grep command to get the MonoFramework version and it was erroring out. A fresh new install of the OS solved my problem

Comment: Wow, that's certainly obscure :)